# Why is Spring trying to create a `redisReferenceResolver` bean?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

My project does use Redis but my unit test mocks it. However it doesn't mock it *enough* because I get this stack trace snippet:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisReferenceResolver': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'redisTemplate' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'redisTemplate' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
```

It is correct. I have carefully ensured there is no redisTemplate bean available because I don't want to run redis in my unit test. But I don't know why it is trying to create the `redisReferenceResolver` bean.

I've turned off autoconfiguration with this:

```
spring:
  profiles: RedisMock
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration
```

(my test has  `@ActiveProfiles({"WebMvcTest","RedisMock"})` in the top)
I do have one class annotated with `@RedisHash` but I need that for my test.
Anyone know what might be triggering the autoconfigure?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`redisReferenceResolver` is defined by Spring Data’s support for Redis-based repositories. Setting `spring.data.redis.repositories.enabled` to `false` and ensuring that you haven’t used `@EnableRedisRepositories` anywhere in your app will disable it.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was the `@EnableRedisRepositories` I had left in there that was the problem. Took that out and it started working. Spend hours yesterday looking for it though and only got there with your answer.